# How to make a box filled with a number?

Tags: html, css

Lets say i have this number `445758`, i want each of these numbers is in the box like this [image]

How to make it happen ?

Comment: please provide code that you have tried so we may assist

Comment: i dont have any idea about this, i'm still trying to figure it out

Comment: You may need javascript for this..would you prefer that?

Comment: then how? @repzero

Comment: You can store the number in a javascript variable and create html elements..would you like a demo?

Comment: yes please, it will be helpful @repzero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//conver the number to a string
var num_string=String(445758);
//loop through each character in the string and insert it into a 
//div which will be inserted into the document.
for(var x=0;x<num_string.length;++x){
var box=document.createElement("div");
box.className="box";
box.innerHTML=num_string[x]
document.getElementsByClassName("code")[0].appendChild(box);

}
```

```css
.box{
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
background:linear-gradient(yellow,white);
margin-right:5px;
margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="code"></div>
```

Comment: don't answer a question that didn't provide a MVCE, just asking to do OP's code.

Comment: what do you mean? @dippas

Comment: this question is too broad most likely it will be closed.

Comment: Sir i want to ask 1 more question, how to put it into '<div class="code"></div>' for example @repzero